# Silverlight 4: Trouble with Value Converters

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I'm trying to use a value converter. However, VS is complaining about this XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DateFormatter x:Key="FormatConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
```

The error:

```
The type 'local:DateFormatter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

Am I missing an assembly reference, or is my XAML incorrect? I'm trying to follow an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28VS.95%29.aspx).

**Update**: I added the following attribute to `UserControl`:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

I also added a DateFormatter class.

Now Intellisense pops up with "local" and "DateFormatter". However, it still gives the same error as above. The error does not occur for other types, such as `App`.

DateFormatter:

```
using System;
...

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class DateFormatter : IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime) value;
            return date.ToShortDateString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `DateFormatter` class in the `MyNamespace` namespace? Also, is the `DateFormatter` class in the same project as your `UserControl`?

Comment: Yes to both your questions. The `DateFormatter` shows up in the Intellisense, but after I pick it VS complains that it can't find the type.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an implementation of your `DateFormatter` that works for me. Please see below.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you need to add an xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication6" to map the namespace and assembly to the XAML namespace local.  If you add the converter via Expression Blend, it will put the correct namespace declaration in for you.

Comment: That produces an error: "A namespace prefix declaration cannot be empty."

Answer (score 3):

As Michael S. Scherotter says, you'll need to add a namespace reference in XAML.

If you're following the MSDN article you'll need to include the following:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOUR-NAMESPACE-HERE"
```

This is similar to a `using` statement in C#. It tells XAML where to find your `DateFormatter` type.

---

**Update:**

I'm not sure what's going wrong for you.

The following works for me (applying your `DateFormatter` code but in a different namespace):

*MainPage.xaml*

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:DateFormatter x:Key="FormatConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Text="{Binding FooDate, Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

```
namespace SilverlightApplication2
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var foo = new Foo { FooDate = DateTime.Now };
            DataContext = foo;
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public DateTime FooDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DateFormmatter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace SilverlightApplication2
{
    public class DateFormatter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return date.ToShortDateString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```